# VirtualBox 4.3 create virtual disk with vboxmanage in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

I am trying to create some virtual disks in a ubuntu 12.04 vm using vboxmanage, but I am recieving errors when I try to do this.

```
vboxmanage createhd --filename /tmp/my_disks/diskfile.vmdk --size 1024
vboxmanage storageattach :id --storagectl SATA Controller --port 1 --device 0 --type hdd --medium /tmp/my_disks/diskfile.vmdk
```

what am I doing wrong here? I am using vagrant to do this and it will work for a ubuntu-12.04 vm template from one site but when I use the ubuntu-12.04 vm from another it breaks. So I am thinking that the commands above may be the problem on the specific vm. Any ideas on how to fix this?(oh and here is the error)

```
VBoxManage: error: Could not find a controller named 'SATA Controller'
```

*I should also mention that I have to use the vm that is not working.

Answer (score -1):

Please try `"SATA Controller"`, with quotes around the two words.